# Windows Server 2008 is not showing DHCP-Server configuration in Server-Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

I've successfully installed the DHCP server role on my Windows Server 2008 R2. After configuring everything, DHCP is working just fine.

I can configure the DHCP server via `Start -> Programs -> Administration -> DHCP`. The problem I'm having is that the configuration of my DHCP doesn't show up in the server-manager.

Any ideas on why it's not showing the sever manager and how I can fix that?

Comment: Do things usually not work out for you then?

Comment: Everything works well. Clients get an IP and their hostnames will be added to the DNS server. I just want to know, why the configurtion of my DHCP won't show up in the server-manager.

Comment: You need to edit your question, as it does not say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the shortcut was not made when you installed the role, for some reason.

Try typing `dhcpmgmt.msc` into the Start Menu search box.

It should also be under `Roles` in `Server Manager` (`ServerManager.msc`).

Comment: Well, now it appears and works. Very strange, really.